# Getting a birthday workflow to work

Tags: formula, workflow, date

I am looking to run a workflow off a birthdate and notify my user that this birthday is coming up in 10 days. I am using this formula:

```
(MONTH( Birthdate)) = MONTH(TODAY()) && (DAY( Birthdate)) = DAY(TODAY()-10)
```

And I can not get the workflow to work and fire off the email. Also can I use this on a static field that is not being updated?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you just want to create a workflow that sends an email to someone 10 days prior to their brithday?

Comment: yes...thats it.

Comment: It looks like sfdcfox has given a very viable solution then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another tidy solution. It requires installing one bit of apex, but no setting up or coding. A declarative solution.

In reports you can subscribe to reports so they regularly run. So I created a generic apex class that you can use in the action. Install the code and then set up the report with your criteria and it can run daily. The report should just show all contacts with a birthday today.

In the report have two columns
1 - ID field
2 - datetime field - Let's say BirthdayUpdate__c

Schedule your report to run daily and execute the declativescheduler action. Each day if it's someone's birthday it will update the datetime field on the record.

Then create a processbuild that fires when the BirthdayUpdate__c field is changed. This can send the email.

I know there are other great solutions above. I just find this method much easier to understand as it actually does a check daily and there aren't lots of future timebased workflows.

Let me know if that helps https://github.com/dthowell/DeclarativeScheduler

Answer (score 11):

1. Create a "Birthday Notification Date" field.
2. Create a Workflow with a Workflow Field Update that checks for an entered birthday and updates the Birthday Notification Date field with the correct value.
3. Create a Time Based Workflow rule that fires on the Birthday Notification Date field, sends the email, and clears the field.

   - Make sure that "recursive mode" is enabled for both workflows.

How it works:

1. User creates or updates a contact with a birthday.
2. The notification field is populated from Workflow Rule #1.
3. The update from the previous step recursively calls Workflow Rule #2 to lock the notification into the Time Based Workflow queue.
4. The user is notified when Workflow Rule #2 performs its delayed actions.
5. The field update from Workflow Rule #2 will recursively call Workflow #1, updating the notification date for the next year.
6. The cycle repeats from step 2.

The appropriate formula for the notification update value would be:

```
DATE(
YEAR(TODAY())+
IF(
    DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(BirthDate), DAY(BirthDate))-10<TODAY(),1,0), 
MONTH(BirthDate), 
DAY(BirthDate))-10
```

Also, it should be noted that you'll have to perform an update on all contacts at least once (batch update) to queue the notifications.

**Edit** Updated formula after sanity check.

**Edit** Does not include February 29th individuals. If that's a concern, one additional check would be needed to bump the date back a day for non-leap years.

Comment: Does the time-based workflow remove the recursive limit on workflows triggering workflows?

Comment: You're limited to five recursions per transaction, so yes, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the formuala to:

```
true
```

(...that's it), and then ad a `Time Trigger` that's set for `10 | Days | Before | Birthdate`.

You might want to add more logic by try making sure `TODAY() < DATE(BirthdayDay, BirthdayMonth, YEAR(TODAY()))` in the formula

Comment: Won't work... The birth date is in the past, so it will fire once, and never again.

Comment: I would approach this in a different way. I would create a Scheduled APEX which would run every day and checks for Users Birthdate and send Appropriate Emails.

Comment: @Jag That works, but there's a non-code solution to the problem.